# Using a batch file through Linux subsystem on Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, batch-file, terminal

I have a batch file that bashes into the linux subsystem I have on Windows 10 that tries to execute commands via the linux system. However, it doesn't execute any commands after the bash command. Here is an example:

`bash
cd Documents/CS/DS`

This just bashes into whatever directory the file is run from instead of CS/DS consistently. Is there anyway to have the batch file execute the rest of the commands?

Comment: Voting to close as **Too broad** : "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question."  Also, Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run bash like that, you are sending execution into that executable. Launch bash as a separate process:

```
`start "bash" bash.exe`
```

Bash won't execute the rest of your cmd script. Cmd.exe processes cmd/bat files, bash only executes bash commands and scripts.

Comment: How would I specify that bash terminal to execute the commands? Doesn't each .bat file open a new terminal? I'm trying to automatically execute commands inside the bash terminal, so that's why I tried to use the same one.

Comment: Write a bash script and pass it as an argument to bash.exe.  Read the [bash docs].(https://www.gnu.org/doc/doc.html).